# Automatically add rack middleware with a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rack

I have a gem that provides some rack middleware, the only way I can get it to work is to place this in my application.rb

```
config.middleware.use "TBBC::Editor::Middleware"
```

How can I make it so that this middleware is automatically used when my gem is used in an apps Gemfile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you intend your gem to be used with Rails 3, you could provide a `Railtie`. You can then automatically load it in case Rails is used.

Assuming your gem's name is `tbbc`, place this in `lib/tbbc/railtie.rb`:

```
module TBBC
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "tbbc.insert_middleware" do |app|
      app.config.middleware.use "TBBC::Editor::Middleware"
    end
  end
end
```

In `lib/tbbc.rb`:

```
require "tbbc/railtie" if defined? Rails
```

You can't automatically add the middleware to generic Rack apps. For non-Rails applications, this will be something the user has to do.

Comment: I cant seem to get that working, I added a puts line to the initializer block and it doesn't look like its ever being executed

Comment: Is the file being loaded though? And is the class a subclass of `Rails::Railtie`?

Comment: The file is being loaded just the block isn't being executed. How would I tell if its a subclass?

Comment: Adding a middleware via a Railtie even is the classic Railtie example, see the official Railtie documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html